Why didn't Jimmy Neutron realize immediately when he read the note on the refrigerator that the note is phony, as the note says "son or daughter..."?
In Jimmy Neutron: Boy Genius (the 2001 film by Nickelodeon), when the aliens abducted Jimmy Neutron's parents, they left a note on the refrigerator saying: "Dear son or daughter, we went to Florida on a long vacation. Parents." (emphasis mine). But Jimmy Neutron has no sister. So, why wasn't it immediately obvious to Jimmy Neutron that the note is fake?

Because he's a dope?

@Valorum He is supposed to be a genious.

He is initially taken in by the alien's extremely clever ruse. There certainly seems to be quite a deal of wishful thinking (mixed with the strong possibility that his shooting star wish has come true) that initially confounds him from spotting the truth

Note that he thought that bribing his mother would get him a trip to the funfair. He's a genius, but he's not that smart.

The statement is logically valid albeit slightly redundant.  As a boy or girl genius myself I appreciate  logically valid statements that include the entire set.

In this instance it seems to be the 'boy' doing the thinking, not the 'genius'

he mightve transitioned since they last saw him

Nothing to back this up, but given my memory of Hugh Neutron (Jimmy's dad), I wouldn't put it past him to write a note like that.  And for Jimmy to expect it.

Isn’t the entire message screaming “fake”? Even starting it with “Dear son” would be odd, as well as ending it with “Parents.” Not to speak of the content itself, “we went to Florida on a long vacation”, without a previous announcement nor a return date. Obviously, it is intended to look fake to every sensible person but taken for granted by this specific receiver. It’s rather surprising they wrote “Florida” rather than “a typical holiday place of this planet”.

Its a joke.  HIs parents were likely joking with him.

This very question was raised on TV Tropes' Headscratchers page for the series (warning: massive time sink), and the explanation offered there was this:

Given that this is right on the heels of him wishing that his parents weren't around so he could have all the fun he wanted, he probably just wanted to believe it, at least for the time, and didn't ask questions until it was clear the lack of parental guidance was doing more harm than good.

This sounds like a plausible explanation to me: he wanted rid of his parents anyway, so he was willing to not ask questions and just roll with it, and it was only after he changed his mind and decided he wanted and/or needed them back that he actually put any thought into the situation.
